# Locking and Unlocking SSH Keys after an amount of time

Tags: ssh, passwords, ssh-keys, authorized-keys

I am trying to have a SSH generated key, where you need to unlock it with a password and then you can login on the server the whole day without password.

But when the day is over, the key should get locked again and you would need to enter a password again to unlock it.

Basically a structure like this:

```
1.: Key locked, enter password to unlock
2.: Password correct: Key unlocked for ... hours
3.: Time out, enter password to renew
```

Comment: What you describe doesn’t exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ssh-agent (or Pageant for PuTTY) – you can load keys into its memory and they will remain unlocked as long as the OS is running, but shutting down the system will forget all keys.

(This *does not* work with the SSH client that comes with Windows, as it stores keys persistently in the Registry, protected with your login password.)

---

If you never shut down your computer (e.g. only suspend it), ssh-agent also allows adding keys with a timeout:

```
$ ssh-add -t 6h ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

If you have a recent OpenSSH version, you can have it automatically add the keys upon first connection by enabling the ~/.ssh/config option:

```
Host *
    AddKeysToAgent 10h
```

Note that this might not work with the SSH client that comes with Windows. Likewise, PuTTY's Pageant does not support timeouts either.